# Gatling : regex to get a specific value from a JSON

Tags: regex, scala, gatling

I have this JSON Object coming from an HTML.

```
{
  "isCompany": false,
  "accommodations": [
    {
      "id": "00000000031000006435",
      "isChecked": false,
      "name": "Théo",
      "addressLine1": "Rue des patriotes 40 Y",
      "addressLine2": "1050 Ixelles",
      "nightsDeclared": 5,
      "schoolNightsDeclared": 3,
      "schoolNightsAttached": 0,
      "taxableNights": 2.0,
      "totalPayment": 0.0,
      "isInProgress": true,
      "isLate": false,
      "isPayed": "false",
      "deadline": "2021-12-31",
      "initialAmount": 0.0,
      "remainingAmount": 0.0
    },
    {
      "id": "00000000031000006438",
      "isChecked": false,
      "name": "Théo",
      "addressLine1": "Rue des Gens 45 B",
      "addressLine2": "1040 Etterbeek",
      "nightsDeclared": 5,
      "schoolNightsDeclared": 3,
      "schoolNightsAttached": 0,
      "taxableNights": 2.0,
      "totalPayment": 0.0,
      "isInProgress": true,
      "isLate": false,
      "isPayed": "false",
      "deadline": "2021-12-31",
      "initialAmount": 0.0,
      "remainingAmount": 0.0
    }
  ]
}
```

I know that in Gatling, it is possible to get the accommodation id by writing this regex :

```
check(regex(""""accommodations":\[\{"id":"(.*?)"""").saveAs("accommodationId"))
```

Now my question is, what is the regex that gets the **"isInProgress"**?

Comment: Why use regex for this and not deserialize and access as a dictionary? I.e. `[a['id'] for a in json.loads(json_string)['accommodations']]`. Also, have you tried to simply replace `id` with the name of the field you want?

Comment: I want to strongly emphasize @DannyVarod's comment.  You have no guarantee that the JSON will continue to look exactly this way.  The RIGHT answer is to use `json.loads` to convert this to a Python structure.  It is less trouble, far less delicate, and no worse in performance than trying a regular expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't!

Using regex in this specific case could result in your code breaking on slight input changes and will result in unreadable code.

Instead deserialize and access as a dictionary?

```py
[a['id'] for a in json.loads(json_string)['accommodations']]
```

Also, have you tried to simply replace `id` with the name of the field you want?

If you insist on using regex for this, check out online regex sites like regex101.com, regexr.com, regextester.com etc. (search for "online regex test") and try to solve this yourself. If your code does not work, ask a question again.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, you have this in your regex

```
"id":"(.*?)"
```

You need just change to expected key name as `isInProgress` or any another. Also pay attention on `"` around `(.*?)` - since the value for `id` a string, they are needed, but value in `isInProgress` with another **type**.